# Find trajectory of particle solving ODE containg integral

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

Please suggest how to solve below linear ODE (I want to plot the r vs t graph), I am trying using Integrate:

```
    f[r_]: = A0/r^3; A0=10^-10;μ = 0.001; b = 4*Pi*a*μ;a=2*10^-6;
    f[r] + b*r'[t] == 0
    Integrate[1/f[r], r] + Integrate[1/b, t] == c0
     
  data = {{7.*10^-6, -0.317175}, {7.7*10^-6, -2.59621}, {8.4*10^-6, 
  \
  -4.03621}, {9.1*10^-6, -4.79394}, {9.8*10^-6, -5.0422}, 
  {0.0000105, \
 -4.94287}, {0.0000112, -4.63177}, {0.0000119, -4.21503}, 
 {0.0000126, \
 -3.76242}, {0.0000133, -3.32148}, {0.000014, -2.91612}, 
   {0.0000147, 
 \
-2.55617}, {0.0000154, -2.24334}, {0.0000161, -1.97411}, 
 {0.0000168, \
  -1.74391}, {0.0000175, -1.5469}, {0.0000182, -1.37765}, 
 {0.0000189, \
  -1.232}, {0.0000196, -1.10604}, {0.0000203, -0.996608}, 
 {0.000021, \
   -0.901123}, {0.0000217, -0.817417}, {0.0000224, -0.743742}, \
  {0.0000231, -0.678649}, {0.0000238, -0.620934}, {0.0000245, \
  -0.569525}, {0.0000252, -0.523687}, {0.0000259, -0.48258}, \
  {0.0000266, -0.445732}, {0.0000273, -0.412469}, {0.000028, 
   -0.382433}};

  f0 = Interpolation[N[data], InterpolationOrder -> 3];
  f[r_] = f0[r]
```

Comment: `Rp` is not defined ?.Your function is: `z[r]` or: `z[t]` ? Decide ?

Comment: Function definitions are written: z[r_] ...

Comment: @Iwaniuk, I have updated the question and corrected the typo Rp.

Comment: What is `fc[r]`? IS it supposed to be `c f[r]`?

Comment: @bmf it was typo. Updated it.

Comment: @GopalVerma firstly, you have to be careful when you edit. What you did is really bad. You edited out the previous question completely, just because you got an answer and replaced it with a completely different question. Edit appropriately, keep the analytic question and just add the numeric. Secondly, in both cases you make the same mistake. You write `r` instead of `r[t]` and then of course Mathematica does not understand what you want to do.

Comment: @bmf, Now I have added our numeric data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what the issue is here. Mathematica is happy to `DSolve` it, unless I am missing something

```
f[r_] := A0/r[t]^3; 
A0 = 10^-10; 
μ = 0.001; 
b = 4*Pi*a*μ; 
a = 2*10^-6;
ode = f[r] + b*r'[t] == 0;

DSolve[ode, r[t], t] // Rationalize[#, 0] &
```

> [image: dsolve]

Comment: Ok, If I have interpolated data for f(r) then how we can get the solution? updated the question.

Comment: @GopalVerma Then you do `NDSolve` for the numerical solution.

Comment: I tried but was not able to get the solution.